# ¿Cuando un array de "x" tipo de dato es inicializado en java, que valor toma por defecto?

Tags: java

Estoy iniciando en esto de la programacion, la verdad se me dificulta el aprendizaje de la misma igual si pudieran darme consejos, la verdad me gustaria trabajar de developer.

Comment: Alan, intenta agregar un ejemplo para poder entenderte.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2):

La pregunta me parece interesante. Espero que puedas mejorarla, para que se adapte al formato del sitio.

Si revisas [la documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) verás los valores por defecto de los tipos primitivos:

```
Tipo                      Valor por defecto
byte                       0
short                      0
int                        0
long                       0L
float                      0.0f
double                     0.0d
char                       '\u0000'
String (u objeto)          null
boolean                    false
```

Cuando creas arrays de cualquiera de esos tipos y los verificas sin asignarles valores, verás que los arrays adoptan los mismos valores según el tipo.

Veamos una prueba de código:

### <kbd>[VER DEMO](http://rextester.com/ECKP57944)</kbd>

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Rextester
{  
    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        System.out.println("Byte:");
        byte[] bytes = new byte[7];          
        for (Byte by : bytes)
            System.out.print(by + " ");

        System.out.println("\n\nShort:");
        short[] shorts = new short[7];          
        for (Short sh : shorts)
            System.out.print(sh + " ");

        System.out.println("\n\nInt:");
        int[] ints = new int[7];          
        for (Integer inte : ints)
            System.out.print(inte + " ");

        System.out.println("\n\nLong:");
        long[] longs = new long[7];          
        for (long lng : longs)
            System.out.print(lng + " ");

        System.out.println("\n\nFloat:");
        float[] floats = new float[7];          
        for (float flt : floats)
            System.out.print(flt + " ");

        System.out.println("\n\nDouble:");
        double[] doubles = new double[7];          
        for (Double dbl : doubles)
            System.out.print(dbl+ " ");

        System.out.println("\n\nChar:");
        char[] arrChars = new char[7];          
        for (char chs : arrChars)
            System.out.print(chs+ " ");


        System.out.println("\n\nString:");
        String str[] = new String[7];
        for (String s : str)
            System.out.print(s + " ");

        System.out.println("\n\nBoolean:");
        boolean bols[] = new boolean[7];
        for (boolean bol : bols)
            System.out.print(bol + " ");

    }
}
```

---

Resultado:

```
Byte:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

Short:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

Int:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

Long:
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

Float:
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 

Double:
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 

Char:


String:
null null null null null null null 

Boolean:
false false false false false false false
```